# How to attribute an ID to a Telerik MVC Window when creating in in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the Telerik MVC controls (which at first glance are impressive) to build an MVC3 Razor application, and have a question about the **Window** control.  I am trying to assign an ID to the **Window** when I create it from JavaScript so that I may reference it at any time using JQuery ... $('WindowID') ... but can't seem to be able to do so.

In short, here is my window:

```
var windowElement = $.telerik.window.create({
        title: "Window opened from JS",
        html: "<strong>Inserting an image...</strong>",
        contentUrl: '',
        modal: false,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        scrollable: false,
        width: 150,
        onClose: function () { }
    })
```

I would like to later, from some other random button or event, be able to move, resize, or close the Window by using it's ID.  The problem is, I haven't been able to assign the **Window** any ID when creating it in JavaScript.

Note:
When I create the **Window** in the Razor view, I can assign a "Name" to the **Window** which DOES allow me to do exactly what I want to.  However, I need to be able to create the **Window** in JavaScript.  I guess I could create a bunch of **Windows** in Razor, then Hide/Show them as needed, but I would like that to be a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for anybody else interested, I eventually figured this out ...

After creating my window in JavaScript (like this):

```
var windowElement = $.telerik.window.create({
    title: "Window opened from JS",
    html: "<strong>Inserting an image...</strong>",
    contentUrl: '',
    modal: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: true,
    scrollable: false,
    width: 150,
    onClose: function () { }
})
```

I used the .attr() jQuery method to assign the 'id' attribute of the Window (like this):

```
windowElement.attr('id', 'myChatID');
```

And that did the trick.

**Note:** Of course, I needed to have the jQuery library referenced for this to work ...

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using the client API this way, but when you use the server API to create Telerik windows, the ID is derived from the Name() method.

Try setting

```
name: "yourid",
```

By the way, you don't need to create the window using Javascript in order to be able to reference it client-side. In fact, you may be making your life more complicated in the process.

I create the window in the MVC view using the server fluent API and use Javascript to show it when required.

...almost all of which I'd not have bothered to mention if I'd read your entire question!

Comment: Thanks Steve!

I have been able to create the Window using the Server API, but I need to be able to create the Window (and maybe multiple Windows) using the JS API because I am creating a chat application, and new chats/replies are given to me in JS functions.
I guess I could create a bunch of Windows in Razor, then Hide/Show them as needed, but I would like that to be a last resort.